# MessageListenerContainer Duplicate Metrics

Tags: spring, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have topic that as a replication and partition factor of 3.

Currently have a Concurrent message listener container setup that will report metrics for each message that is consumed.

For some reason, certain metrics are reporting multiple times and I am not sure why.maybe it's an issue with spring-kafka and not kafka itself?

```
public void consumerMetrics() {
    for (MessageListenerContainer messageListenerContainer : kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.getListenerContainers()) {
        Map<String, Map<MetricName, ? extends Metric>> metrics = messageListenerContainer.metrics();
        metrics.forEach( (clientid, metricMap) -> {
            System.out.println("for client id:" + clientid);
            metricMap.forEach((metricName, metricValue) -> {
                String cMetricName = metricName.name();
                double cMetricValue = metricValue.value();
                String cMetricNameClean = cMetricName.replaceAll("[-|.]", "_");
                System.out.println(clientid + " | " + cMetricNameClean + 
            });
        });
    }
}
```

when i print the metrics, i receive duplicates...sometimes 2 sometimes 3 all with different values

kafka-health-check-0 | outgoing_byte_rate : 4.509248897373444
kafka-health-check-0 | outgoing_byte_rate : 7.905659134330325
kafka-health-check-0 | outgoing_byte_rate : 4.5120706122583405

Comment: @GaryRussell please help

Comment: @Gary Russell any thoughts?

Comment: All we do is assemble the metrics for each consumer (for example if concurrency > 1) into a map keyed by the client id. If you are seeing multiple entries for the same client id then that's what the consumer gave us. If concurrency is 1, the map will have one entry. See the code in `ConcurrentListenerContainer.getMetrics()` and `KafkaMessageListenerContainer.getMetrics()`. Maybe set a breakpoint there?

Comment: @GaryRussell'm hmm okay.  Is it possible for me to return a specific partition listener from the listenercontainer and only poll metrics for the specific listener rather than the entire container?....for example                                                                                                                                      I receive a message in partition-0...then only return the metrics for parition-0 listener?

Answer (score 0):

The `ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer` has a method `getContainers()` (it's not on `MessageListenerContainer` so you will have to cast).

```
/**
 * Return the list of {@link KafkaMessageListenerContainer}s created by
 * this container.
 * @return the list of {@link KafkaMessageListenerContainer}s created by
 * this container.
 */
public List<KafkaMessageListenerContainer<K, V>> getContainers() {
```

You can call that and iterate over the list, calling `getAssignedPartitions()` to figure out which one you are interested in and then call `metrics()` on it to just get its consumer metrics.